# Setting and removing the 'required' attribute using javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function, all im trying to do is if the first radio button is selected, then hide a few input fields and make them not required by the form. Then is the other radio button is selected then show those hidden fields and make them required by the form. The user may change between the radio buttons, and so the show hide operation and adding and removing of the required attributes have to happen on radio button change. At the moment the fields are showing and hiding but i cannot change the required attributes. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'watch-me') {
            $('#show-me').show();  
            $('#1041827741').setAttribute("required", "");
            $('#1283215174').setAttribute("required", "");
            $('#1496644528').setAttribute("required", "");
            $('#1392644643').setAttribute("required", "");
            $('#1321281340').setAttribute("required", "");
       }

       else {
            $('#show-me').hide();
            $('#1041827741').removeAttr('required');
            $('#1283215174').removeAttr('required');
            $('#1496644528').removeAttr('required');
            $('#1392644643').removeAttr('required');
            $('#1321281340').removeAttr('required');
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: <div class="dmforminput dmRespDesignCol small-12 required newLine large-4 medium-4" id="1463448757"> <label for="dmform-0" id="1745894405"> Name: </label> <input type="text" class="" name="dmform-0" id="1374778995"/> <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-0" value="Name" id="1765745438"/> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Use the prop() method:

```
$('#1041827741').prop('required',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .prop("required", true / false) to set and remove. Also, setAttribute and removeAttribute methods are native DOM methods which directly operate on the element.

If you do not have an option of changing the elements markup you could modify your code to save some typings.

Here is what you could do to fix.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

    var ids = ["#1041827741", "#1283215174", "#1496644528", "#1392644643", "#1321281340"];

    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'watch-me') {
      $('#show-me').show();
      ids.forEach((id) => $(id).prop("required", true));
    } else {
      $('#show-me').hide();
      ids.forEach((id) => $(id).prop("required", false));
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if you do have options to change the elements, I would assign a same class name to all of those elements and just operate on the ids.

Here is what it can be done.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'watch-me') {
      $('#show-me').show();
      //inputElement is the class assigned to all input elements
      $(".inputElement").prop("required", true);
    } else {
      $('#show-me').hide();
      $(".inputElement").prop("required", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe the problem is which ID I am referring to:

Comment: <div class="dmforminput dmRespDesignCol small-12 required newLine large-4 medium-4" id="1463448757">
         <label for="dmform-0" id="1745894405">
          Name:
         </label>
         <input type="text" class="" name="dmform-0" id="1374778995"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-0" value="Name" id="1765745438"/>
        </div>

Comment: In this case I should be id number 1374778995 right?

Comment: I dont understand your question here. Can you please be specific?